# Inversa de una matriz

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy haciendo un programa que saca por pantalla la matriz inversa, el determinante, la de cofactores etc... Pero no consigo imprimir por pantalla la matriz resultante de cada una. ¿Cómo puedo llamar a cada función y sacar la matriz resultante de cada una de las funciones para que quede visualmente como una matriz? 
El código es el siguiente:

```
package inversamatriz;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InversaMatriz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numCarx = 0;
        int numCary = 0;
        System.out.print("Introduzca el número de caracteres de filas de la primera matriz: ");
        numCarx = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduzca el número de caracteres de columnas de la primera matriz: ");
        numCary = scan.nextInt();
        double M1[][] = new double[numCarx][numCary];
        for(int x=0; x<numCarx; x++){
            for(int i=0; i<numCary; i++){
                System.out.print("x"+(i+1)+" = ");
                M1[x][i]=scan.nextInt();
            }

        }
        System.out.print("Introduzca el número de caracteres de filas de la segunda matriz: ");
        numCarx = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduzca el número de caracteres de columnas de la segunda matriz: ");
        numCary = scan.nextInt();
        double M2[][] = new double[numCarx][numCary];
        for(int x=0; x<numCarx; x++){
            for(int i=0; i<numCary; i++){
                System.out.print("x"+(i+1)+" = ");
                M2[x][i]=scan.nextInt();
            }
        }


    }

    public static double[][] matrizInversa(double[][] matriz) {
        double det=1/determinante(matriz);
        double[][] nmatriz=matrizAdjunta(matriz);
        multiplicarMatriz(det,nmatriz);
        return nmatriz;
    }

    public static void multiplicarMatriz(double n, double[][] matriz) {
        for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<matriz.length;j++)
                matriz[i][j]*=n;
    }

    public static double[][] matrizAdjunta(double [][] matriz){
        return matrizTranspuesta(matrizCofactores(matriz));
    }

    public static double[][] matrizCofactores(double[][] matriz){
        double[][] nm=new double[matriz.length][matriz.length];
        for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<matriz.length;j++) {
                double[][] det=new double[matriz.length-1][matriz.length-1];
                double detValor;
                for(int k=0;k<matriz.length;k++) {
                    if(k!=i) {
                        for(int l=0;l<matriz.length;l++) {
                            if(l!=j){
                                int indice1=k<i ? k : k-1 ;
                                int indice2=l<j ? l : l-1 ;
                                det[indice1][indice2]=matriz[k][l];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                detValor=determinante(det);
                nm[i][j]=detValor * (double)Math.pow(-1, i+j+2);
            }
        }
        return nm;
    }

    public static double[][] matrizTranspuesta(double [][] matriz){
        double[][]nuevam=new double[matriz[0].length][matriz.length];
        for(int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matriz.length; j++)
                nuevam[i][j]=matriz[j][i];
        }
        return nuevam;
    }

    public static double determinante(double[][] matriz){
        double det;
        if(matriz.length==2){
            det=(matriz[0][0]*matriz[1][1])-(matriz[1][0]*matriz[0][1]);
            return det;
        }
        double suma=0;
        for(int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++){
        double[][] nm=new double[matriz.length-1][matriz.length-1];
            for(int j=0; j<matriz.length; j++){
                if(j!=i){
                    for(int k=1; k<matriz.length; k++){
                        int indice=-1;
                        if(j<i)
                            indice=j;
                        else if(j>i)
                            indice=j-1;
                            nm[indice][k-1]=matriz[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(i%2==0)
                suma+=matriz[i][0] * determinante(nm);
            else
                suma-=matriz[i][0] * determinante(nm);
        }
        return suma;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, bastaría con llamar este método al final de la ejecución de cada método.

```
public void printMatriz(double[][] mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: **Evitar realizar publicación de respuestas duplicadas**, esta [respuesta la publicaste en otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129672/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-llamar-a-cada-funci%C3%B3n-y-sacar-la-matriz-resultante-de-cada-una-de-la/129884#129884), revisar [answer]